# SQLi - how to dump data without knowing table & field names?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

A rather specific question, but I'm trying to SQL inject a vulnerable web app to enumerate data. I have permission to do this.

The gist of it is there are some params, lets say 4 of them being sent to the app in a post request. 2 of them are not sent to the SQL query, the other 2 are.

I've forced an error from the app that shows me the query being run, which looks like:

```
select * from some_table  where some_field='<param 3>' and some_other_field='<param 4>'
```

If I do **' or '1=1** for both params, I successfully enumerate a record that is not mine, but only a single record for some reason.

I can surmise that this table has at least the column names **some_field** and **some_other_field**, but I don't know the names of the other columns in this table, nor do I know any of the other table names.
Also the data that is returned by the app to me from this injection does not seem to provide the exact column names, and the values for **some_field** and **some_other_field** for the enumerated record are not returned in the response.

How can I leverage this to get more information from the web app?

I've tried using SQLmap but the only thing that's done for me is say that the backend dbms is probably Oracle. After 20-30 runs with different settings it doesn't even think these params are injectable, but I was able to do this manually, so it is. Kinda stumped.

Comment: In general you do this by querying `information_schema`. Oracle is non-standard in this regard so you have to use `all_tables` and `all_tab_columns` instead. Lots of things can potentially upset SQLmap - encoding, length limits, blocked characters, etc.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for that clarification. It seemed to be something with the way the app worked I guess, it only gave maximum 1 record whether u injected a command or not, and it didn't seem to be returning all the fields from the table even though the sent query was select * from <table>. Querying information_schema/all tables had no effect either, I presume because some part of the app was filtering out anything that didn't match a specific return field/attribute, which is why I was wondering how to do anything if I can't get any info from the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually figured this out, apparently you can just send "ORDER BY" if you don't know the table/field details and it will vary the output if the application is vulnerable but only returns a limited number of entries.

Still not sure why sqlmap was having such a hard time with it though.